# Migrate file in php

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a Laravel project. We currently have a config file for our customer (number of data they can store, their type ...). The config file is config.php.example. When we deploy to our customer, we change the config.php.example to config.php and modify the content of config.php to fit our customer demand

The problem is that the config file (config.php.example) will continuously change due to business goal. And when someone add some config, our team must check all the old config and compare them with the new one. I believe that it is not a good way to solve this problem. I guess we can do something like a migration for a PHP file

I tried to search but it does not work. Could anyone give me some keywords about this situation ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you put your config in a database and use database migrations?

Comment: you should use DB table for that. config file is not a dynamic storage

Comment: Peter and Zahid: Thanks but we could not do that because when we install on-premise for our customer, our database is on their hand and they can modify and change the config to get the full option. We can encode our php code using ioncube so that is not a problem for us.

Comment: This work relates more to a DevOps than a developer. I just want to know how other software handle this

Comment: What about version-control system like Git or SVN?

Comment: I am using git to control our source code. I track config.php.example file and ignore the config.php file. When we update our code, config.php.example file will pull the latest code and we have to manual change the config.php file. Are there any solution given by git in this situation ?

Comment: I can see here a mixture of issues. One is that the project should be versioned/branched based on those changes that brake the previous configuration. On the other hand, a config file isn't the best place to store customer specific parameters, why not to use environment variables?

Comment: Adrian: The goal is to keep our config secretly, so we encode the config.php file. How can we use environment variables in this case ?